# Am I doing something wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, dictionary

The website I learn python on doesn't explain the dictionaries well so I resort to this.What I'm supposed to do is find the average of the 3 of these room's temperatures over how many days the user types(maximum is 3). Each day has 4 temperatures over 1 day. When I run this code, it doesn't produce any temperatures for the 3 rooms.

```
hi={}
days=int(input('How many days of data do you have? '))
print('Average Temperatures:')
f = open('temps1.txt')
g= open('temps1.txt') and open('temps2.txt')
o=open('temps1.txt') and open('temps2.txt') and open('temps3.txt')
if days=='1':
  for line in f:
    parts = line.strip().split(",")
    if parts[0] not in hi:
      hi[parts[0]] = []
    hi[parts[0]].append(int(val[1]))
elif days=='2':
  for line in g:
    parts = line.strip().split(",")
    if parts[0] not in hi:
      hi[parts[0]] = []
    hi[parts[0]].append(int(val[1]))
elif days=='3':
  for line in o:
    parts = line.strip().split(",")
    if parts[0] not in hi:
      hi[parts[0]] = []
    hi[parts[0]].append(int(val[1]))

for k, v in hi.items():
  print("Room: {}, Avg: {}".format(k, sum(v)/days*4))
```

temps1.txt activates only when 1 is typed by the user in the input question:

```
Living Room,23
Bedroom,24
Kitchen,22
Living Room,24
Bedroom,26
Kitchen,22
Living Room,25
Bedroom,26
Kitchen,23
Living Room,24
Bedroom,26
Kitchen,23
```

temps2.txt only activates when the user enters 2 in the first question(this is used alongside temps1.txt):

```
Living Room,26
Bedroom,24
Kitchen,23
Living Room,27
Bedroom,24
Kitchen,24
Living Room,28
Bedroom,25
Kitchen,26
Living Room,29
Bedroom,26
Kitchen,28
```

temps3.txt only activates when the user enters 3 in the first question(this is used alongside temps1.txt and temps2.txt):

```
Living Room,28
Bedroom,29
Kitchen,28
Living Room,28
Bedroom,30
Kitchen,29
Living Room,29
Bedroom,29
Kitchen,31
Living Room,21
Bedroom,23
Kitchen,21
```

Am I able to produce a code to do this but with no imports of the sort? Also one more thing, am I able to assign variables to 'for in' statements and 'if' statements?

Comment: `open(..)` returns the handle for one file. What do you hope to achieve by combining multiple file handles via `and`?  Doku: [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: You cast `days` to an integer but you try to compare it as a string in `if days=='1'`. This won't work. BTW, `g = open('temps1.txt') and open('temps2.txt')` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

Lets split data file creation and processing to make this a [minimal verifyable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - answer:

```
def createData():
    """Create demo data as files 'temp1.txt','temp2.txt','temp3.txt'"""
    with open("temp1.txt","w") as f:
        f.write("""Living Room,23
Bedroom,24\nKitchen,22\nLiving Room,24\nBedroom,26\nKitchen,22\nLiving Room,25\nBedroom,26\nKitchen,23\nLiving Room,24\nBedroom,26\nKitchen,23\n""")

    with open("temp2.txt","w") as f:
        f.write("""Living Room,26\nBedroom,24\nKitchen,23\nLiving Room,27\nBedroom,24\nKitchen,24\nLiving Room,28\nBedroom,25\nKitchen,26\nLiving Room,29\nBedroom,26\nKitchen,28\n""")

    with open("temp3.txt","w") as f:
        f.write("""Living Room,28\nBedroom,29\nKitchen,28\nLiving Room,28\nBedroom,30\nKitchen,29\nLiving Room,29\nBedroom,29\nKitchen,31\nLiving Room,21\nBedroom,23\nKitchen,21\n""")
```

With this demo data we start the user input and calculation. We read all needed data from 1 to 3 files into one dict and output it:

```
# create all data files  
createData()    

# process data 
nrDays = 0

# ask for how many days, catch invalid values until valid one is given
while nrDays not in range(1,4):
    try:
        nrDays=input('How many days of data do you have? [1-3] ')
        nrDays=int(nrDays)
    except: # catchall
        print("Parsing error. 1 to 3 allowed. {} given".format(nrDays))

# read data only from files needed  
temps = {}
for d in range(1,nrDays+1): 
    # format file names as temp1.txt to temp3.txt as needed
    with open ("temp{}.txt".format(d),"r") as f:  # open file
        for line in f:
            if line.strip():     # if line not empty, f.e. dangling newline at end
                room,temp = line.strip().split(",")
                temp = int(temp)   # convert to int
                k = temps.setdefault(room,[]) # creates the empty list if needed
                                              # returns the value if present
                k.append(temp)

print('Average Temperatures:')  

for k, v in temps.items():
      print("Room: {}, Avg: {}".format(k, sum(v)/len(v))) # get the length from the list
```

Output:

```
How many days of data do you have? 3
Average Temperatures:
Room: Living Room, Avg: 26.0
Room: Bedroom, Avg: 26.0
Room: Kitchen, Avg: 25.0

How many days of data do you have? 2
Average Temperatures:
Room: Living Room, Avg: 25.75
Room: Bedroom, Avg: 25.125
Room: Kitchen, Avg: 23.875

How many days of data do you have? 1
Average Temperatures:
Room: Living Room, Avg: 24.0
Room: Bedroom, Avg: 25.5
Room: Kitchen, Avg: 22.5
```

If you input anything beside 1-3 you either get a new input prompt (if int inputted) or a message and a new prompt (if no int given).